# Bar Chart showing nil in swift

Tags: swift, ios-charts

I am using the Charts library to show bar charts but it still shows nil. I have set the view as `BarChartView`.

```
@IBOutlet weak var barChartView: BarChartView!

func setChart() {
   var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = []
   for i in 0..<testArray.count {
      let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: Double(testArray[i]))
      dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
    }

    let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(entries: dataEntries, label: "logs")
    let chartData = BarChartData(dataSet: chartDataSet)

    barChartView.data = chartData
}
```

and I do call `setChart()` in `viewDidLoad()`

[image]

Comment: What is the output of `print(dataEntries)`?

Comment: wow, thanks. turns out it's an empty array (`[ ]`), even though test array has integers. could you tell the reason for that?

Comment: No idea, I am not familiar with iOS charts. I recommend you step through each line and inspect the values. Make sure that each `dataEntry` is what you want.